# how to INSERT data in MySQL from GRAFANA dashbord

Tags: mysql

Is is possible to update data or insert data from grafana to mysql. I have a requirement to insert/update information in mysql using a UI. Now I am already using grafana so wanted to know if there is any way we can use grafana to update or insert information